# removing a column from a CSV file in python

Tags: python

I am attempting to remove a duplicate column from a csv file in Python3.  I am able to get the code to run without error...however when I attempt to print the number of rows processed I receive a blank response in codio.

The response to running comes back as 1001codio@sigma-portal:~/workspace$

Can anyone point out how I can fix this?  Ideally I would like it to print how many columns were deleted.

```
import csv
import re
data = []

import csv

input_file = 'customerdata.csv'
output_file = 'outputcustomerdata.csv'
cols_to_remove = [11] # Column indexes to be removed (starts at 0)

cols_to_remove = sorted(cols_to_remove, reverse=True) # Reverse so we remove from the end first
row_count = 0 # Current amount of rows processed

with open(input_file, "r") as source:
   reader = csv.reader(source)
   with open(output_file, "wt") as result:
       writer = csv.writer(result)
       for row in reader:
           row_count += 1
           print('\r{0}'.format(row_count), end='') # Print rows processed
           for col_index in cols_to_remove:
               del row[col_index]
           writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: check the length of `reader`

Comment: I recomend using pandas if you have to modify csv files

Answer (score 1):

Try pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('customerdata.csv')
df = df.drop('column_name', axis=1)

# save your file
df.to_csv('outputcustomerdata.csv', encoding='utf-8')

print(df)
```

Comment: Codio does not recognize the pandas module :(

Comment: You have to install it.
Try ```pip install pandas``` or ```pip3 install pandas``` on your terminal